# JQuery animation in not working in angular 5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Z2Lu5/) example of how to create a fixed colapsable footer using Angular 5 with .netcore 2.0. I am trying to use the example in an angular 5 application but the animation is not playing nor the alert is being called for `$('#collapseOne').on` But the test button alerts the success message as A quick test to see if the jQuery is set up properly.

TypeScript:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#test').click('click', function (e) {
        alert('success');
    });
    $('#collapseOne').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        alert('success')
        $('.panel-heading').animate({

          backgroundColor: "#515151"
      }, 500);
    })

    $('#collapseOne').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        alert('success')
        $('.panel-heading').animate({
          backgroundColor: "#00B4FF"
      }, 500);
    })
  });
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="test">test</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['operatorControl'],sidebar: ['List'] } }]">
          Click Me
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, adipisci, quibusdam, minima ratione voluptas quidem porro sint nobis odio cupiditate alias nisi. Magnam et fugiat labore eum at adipisci ex.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use Angular animations if your creating an Angular app?

Comment: I'm guessing Angular animations use css animations, which are **a lot** faster than jQuery's. If you *need* animations in jQuery for some reason, then check out jQuery transit. Great little tool.

Comment: Thanks, Guys i will use angular animations I dont need to use jquery. Its that I was looking for a fixed footer thats collapsable and that was the example I came accross.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-cli app, please follow the steps provided below:

1. install jQuery using npm

**npm install jquery — save**

2. go to the ./angular-cli.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery

**"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]**

3. Now to use jQuery, all you have to do is to import it as follows in the component you want to use jQuery

**import * from 'jquery';**

Or

**declare var $: any;**

Comment: I have done all these steps. But I'll Do what they suggested in the comments above. `$('#test')` works so I dont know why ` $('#collapseOne')` dont work.

Comment: In my thoughts, the simple jQuery animations should be working. It is bootstrap animation events that must be failing. Can you confirm the bootstrap animations are working into above example?

Answer (score 0):

install jquery

```
npm install --save jquery
```

in *angular.json* set these :

```
"options": {
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ]
      },
```

in your .ts file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

in your app.module.ts file:

```
window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;
```